# Keeping up with (para)chains and their endpoints

Tags: polkadot-js, wallet

Let's say I want to build a wallet, and instead of adding chains manually, I want to track and add/remove them automatically.

My idea was to combine the data in the [ss58-registry](https://github.com/paritytech/ss58-registry/blob/main/ss58-registry.json) and the [production endpoints](https://github.com/polkadot-js/apps/blob/0884b314ae78f7f4187ca6777d4bd40ce47acc2d/packages/apps-config/src/endpoints/production.ts) (the `network` and `info` attributes seem to match), so I have access to both the token and account info as well as endpoints.

Is there an easier or more reliable way of doing that? Or a recommended way?

Comment: Would also be good to have multiple for each and also list archive nodes for if you're going back far in time. Would it be too recursive for us to store this data on chain somewhere? but who would own / update the info?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no official registry of parachain information at the moment; the ss58-registry is about as close to official as it can be.

So doing something like you are suggesting is a solid choice in my opinion.